# how to find the percent of word appearance in a file

Tags: bash

I have a word and I want to check what the percent of its appearance in a file ( according to the total number of word in the file ) ? For example if I have the word "you" and it appears 2 times in a file with 8 words the output will be 25%.

I tried:
fgrep -ow

Answer (score 2):

you can get the total numbers of words in your file as follow

```
nw=`wc -w < /path/to/file`
```

And the number of occurrences of a certain word/pattern with

```
occurrences=`egrep -c <pattern> /path/to/file`
```

then you can easily calculate the percentage and put the result in a variable

```
result=`echo "scale=2; $occurrences*100/$nw" | bc`
```

to add the `%` you can eg. do as follow

```
echo $result'%'
```

Comment: tnx!! but how i can sdd % near the result?

Comment: you welcome, it was funny to test, i ll update the answer ; )

Answer (score 0):

Use the same logic as shown [URL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-text-file-with-the-comma)

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file.txt | awk '{if($0=="her"){nmw+=1}}END{print ((nmw*100)/NR)}'
```

Comment: Assumes all words are separated by spaces.

Comment: tnx, but for some reason it not working, it gives me 0 as output. what is "her" ?

Comment: replace `her` with string you want to search so for your case it is `you`.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -vw="word" 'BEGIN{RS="[^a-zA-Z]+"} $0==w{c++} END{printf "%.1f%%\n",c*100/NR}' file
```

- `-vw="word"` gives `awk` the variable `w` which contains "word". That is the word, you want to have the percentage.
- `BEGIN{RS="[^a-zA-Z]+"}` sets the row separator to everything, but letter, so every word is processed separately.
- `$0==w{c++}` increase the counter if the word is found.
- `END{printf "%.1f%%\n",c*100/NR}` print the calculated number after the file is processed