# Count lines containing word

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with multiple lines. I want to know, for each word that appears in the total file, how many lines contain that word, for example:

```
0 hello world the man is world
1 this is the world
2 a different man is the possible one
```

The result I'm expecting is:

```
0:1
1:1
2:1
a:1
different:1
hello:1
is:3
man:2
one:1
possible:1
the:3
this:1
world:2
```

Note that the count for "world" is 2, not 3, since the word appears on 2 lines. Because of this, translating blanks to newline chars wouldn't be the exact solution.

Comment: What have you try to the moment?

Comment: This seems highly relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332890/224077

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another Perl variant, using [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)

```
$ perl -MList::Util=uniq -alne '
  map { $h{$_}++ } uniq @F }{ for $k (sort keys %h) {print "$k: $h{$k}"}
' file
0: 1
1: 1
2: 1
a: 1
different: 1
hello: 1
is: 3
man: 2
one: 1
possible: 1
the: 3
this: 1
world: 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Straightfoward-ish in bash:

```sh
declare -A wordcount
while read -ra words; do 
    # unique words on this line
    declare -A uniq
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do 
        uniq[$word]=1
    done
    # accumulate the words
    for word in "${!uniq[@]}"; do 
        ((wordcount[$word]++))
    done
    unset uniq
done < file
```

Looking at the data:

```
$ declare -p wordcount
declare -A wordcount='([possible]="1" [one]="1" [different]="1" [this]="1" [a]="1" [hello]="1" [world]="2" [man]="2" [0]="1" [1]="1" [2]="1" [is]="3" [the]="3" )'
```

and formatting as you want:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${!wordcount[@]}" | sort | while read key; do echo "$key:${wordcount[$key]}"; done
0:1
1:1
2:1
a:1
different:1
hello:1
is:3
man:2
one:1
possible:1
the:3
this:1
world:2
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a pretty straight-forward perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %words = ();
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my %linewords = ();
  map { $linewords{$_}=1 } split / /;
  foreach my $word (keys %linewords) {
    $words{$word}++;
  }
}

foreach my $word (sort keys %words) {
  print "$word:$words{$word}\n";
}
```

The basic idea is to loop over the input; for each line, split it into words, then save those words into a hash (associative array) in order to remove any duplicates, then loop over that array of words and add one to an overall counter for that word. At the end, report on the words and their counts.

Comment: A slight problem with this is in my opinion that it does not respect what the usual definition of a word is, since it splits on a single space character.
If two spaces were found somewhere, an empty string inbetween would be considered a word as well if I'm not mistaken.
Let alone if words were separated by other punctuation characters.
Of course, it was not specified in the question whether "word" is understood as the programmer's concept of a "word", or as a word of a natural language.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that calls several programs from a shell:

`fmt -1 words.txt | sort -u | xargs -Ipattern sh -c 'echo "pattern:$(grep -cw pattern words.txt)"'`

A little explanation:

The `fmt -1 words.txt` prints out all the words, 1 per line, and the `| sort -u` sorts this output and extracts only the unique words from it.

In order to count the occurences of a word in a file, one can use `grep` (a tool meant to search files for patterns). By passing the `-cw` option, grep gives the number of word matches it finds. So you can find the total number of occurrences of `pattern` using `grep -cw pattern words.txt`.

The tool `xargs` allows us to do this for each and every single word output by `sort`. The `-Ipattern` means that it will execute the following command multiple times, replacing each occurrence of pattern with a word it reads from standard input, which is what it gets from `sort`.

The indirection with `sh` is needed because `xargs` only knows how to execute a single program, given it's name, passing everything else as arguments to it. `xargs` does not handle things like command substitution. The `$(...)` is command substitution in the above snippet, as it substitutes the output from `grep` into `echo`, allowing it to be formatted correctly. Since we need the command substitution, we must use the `sh -c` command which runs whatever it recieves as an argument in its own shell.

Comment: An optimisation to this approach: `fmt -1 words.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 ":" $1 }'`

Comment: @matja is `sort | uniq -c` more efficient than `sort -u`?

Comment: vikarjramun@ no, but uniq -c gives you the counts of each word in one pass, so you don't have to use xargs to do multiple passes of the input file for each word.

Comment: @matja: I actually made the answer you provided before the current one. However, it does not do what OP asked for. I misread the question at first entirely as well, and was corrected by glenn jackman.
What you are suggesting would count every occurrence of each word.
What OP asked for is to count the number of lines each word occurs in at least once.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple alternative would be to use Python (>3.6). This solution has the same problem as the one mentioned by @Larry in his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492501/count-lines-containing-word#comment904230_492514).

```python
from collections import Counter

with open("words.txt") as f:
    c = Counter(word for line in [line.strip().split() for line in f] for word in set(line))
    for word, occurrence in sorted(c.items()):
        print(f'{word}:{occurrence}')
        # for Python 2.7.x compatibility you can replace the above line with 
        # the following one:
        # print('{}:{}'.format(word, occurrence))
```

A more explicit version version of the above:

```python
from collections import Counter


FILENAME = "words.txt"


def find_unique_words():
    with open(FILENAME) as f:
        lines = [line.strip().split() for line in f]

    unique_words = Counter(word for line in lines for word in set(line))
    return sorted(unique_words.items())


def print_unique_words():
    unique_words = find_unique_words()
    for word, occurrence in unique_words:
        print(f'{word}:{occurrence}')


def main():
    print_unique_words()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
0:1
1:1
2:1
a:1
different:1
hello:1
is:3
man:2
one:1
possible:1
the:3
this:1
world:2
```

The above also assumes that *words.txt* is on the same directory as *script.py*. Note that this is not much different from other solutions provided here, but perhaps somebody will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, though doesn't care if it reads the file many times:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' file.txt | sort | uniq | while read -r word; do
  printf "%s:%d\n" "$word" "$(grep -Fw "$word" file.txt | wc -l)"
done
```

EDIT: Despite converting spaces to newlines, this does count lines that have an occurrence of each word and not the occurrences of the words themselves. It gives the result:

```
0:1
1:1
2:1
a:1
different:1
hello:1
is:3
man:2
one:1
possible:1
the:3
this:1
world:2
```

which is character-by-character identical to OP's example result.

Comment: Read the question again. It literally says `translating blanks to newline chars wouldn't be the exact solution`.

Comment: @Sparhawk Read the answer again. This does give the answer he gave as example, including giving the result of 2 instead of 3 for world. He meant that doing something like `sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort | uniq -c` would not work because it'd give the answer 3 for world, but that's not what this answer does. It correctly counts the lines where the words occur and not the occurrences themselves, just like OP wanted.

Comment: Ah right, apologies! I would recommend putting in an explanation of your code, which is both helpful to the questioner, and clarifies what it does. Also, as a minor point, you probably want `read -r` here.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do it with awk:

**count.awk**:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# count line containing word

{
    for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {
        word_in_a_line[$i] ++
        if (word_in_a_line[$i] == 1) {
            word_line_count[$i] ++
        }
    }

    delete word_in_a_line
}

END {
    for (word in word_line_count){
        printf "%s:%d\n",word,word_line_count[word]
    }
}
```

Run it by:

```
$ awk -f count.awk ./test.data | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure bash answer

```
echo "0 hello world the man is world
1 this is the world
2 a different man is the possible one" | while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do echo $line | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u; done | sort | uniq -c


   1 0
   1 1
   1 2
   1 a
   1 different
   1 hello
   3 is
   2 man
   1 one
   1 possible
   3 the
   1 this
   2 world
```

I looped unique words on each line and passed it to `uniq -c`

edit: I did not see glenn's answer. I found it strange to not see a bash answer